# Content Js Function Not Linked Error - "Function Not Defined "

Tags: javascript, function, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

working on a Firefox addon I am Calling a content js and an html page using the add-on script below is the code snippet for the add-on script.

```
var textChk = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    position: {
        top: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    hight: 100,
    contentURL: data.url("textChk.html"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("content.js")
});
function handleClick() {
    textChk.show();
    textChk.port.on("first-para", function(firstPara) {
      console.log(firstPara);
    });
    textChk.port.emit("get-first-para");
}
```

and the code for the content script is as follows

```
function loginChk()
{
    self.port.on("get-first-para", getFirstPara);
}

function getFirstPara() {
    var userId = document.getElementById("usermail").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (userId.length > 0 && pass.length > 0) {
        var firstPara = userId + " ** " + pass;
        self.port.emit("first-para", firstPara);
    }
}
```

now when i call the loginChk() function i get the following error

```
ReferenceError: loginChk is not defined
```

I am unable to figure out where is the issue as this was working earlier in another add-on code . can someone please suggest me how to rectify this error ?

Comment: Did you end up getting any help on any of your topics yet?

Comment: No nothing much yet .,, send me the link if you are available on irc now ..

Comment: I'm on IRC but not free right now :( but jump on ill be free in like 45min :) https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23introduction

Answer (score 2):

We discussed a bit over IRC, but just for future reference.

You can start using "./" as shortcut for data folder (therefore you don't need to require data module anymore for such trivial matter); and remove the `contentScriptFile`:

```
var textChk = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  position: {
    top: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  hight: 100,
  contentURL: "./textChk.html"
});
```

"content.js" can be included directly in your "textChk.html" file, just with a script tag:

```
<!-- textChk.html -->
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- meta, etc -->
     <script src="content.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!-- rest of your file, body, etc -->
</html>
```

From `content.js`, now you can send and receive message directly from your add-on code, using `addon.port` instead of `self.port`, see the [documentation about sdk panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) for further details.

The `handleClick`, that I supposed is related to a click of a button – by the way, do you know you can [attach a panel to a button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Attaching_panels_to_buttons)? – that shows the panel, can also a bit improved. First of all, you can just add the listener outside, otherwise you'll add a new listener every time you show the panel and you probably want that once. Plus, you want get the paragraph only when the panel is shown, so:

```
var textChk = require("sdk/panel").Panel({ /* ...*/ });

textChk.port.on("first-para", (firstPara) => console.log(firstPara));

textChk.on("show", () => textChk.port.emit("get-first-para"));

function handleClick() {
  textChk.show();
}
```

That is would be already a better events flow.

Said that, without the code that actually call `loginChk` I can't tell what's wrong, because I cannot see the flow of your add-on.
What I can tell, if `loginChk` is actually adding only a listener, you don't need that, you can just put as I did without wrapping it in any functions.

Hope that it helps.